# Why does the partial autocorrelation exceed 1.0?

Tags: python, time-series, regression

I used statsmodels.tsa.stattools.pscf (python module) to calculate an autocorrelation of time series. Although the range of the autocorrelation must be from -1 to 1, the return computed by stattools.pscf exceed it. Why?

```
a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5])
cor=sm.tsa.stattools.pacf(a,nlags=5,method='yw')
print(cor)
[ 1.          0.22222222 -0.44642857 -0.55588139 -0.50024995  1.49605777]
```

When the lag is 5, autocorrelation is over 1.0

```
a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,9])
cor=sm.tsa.stattools.pacf(a,nlags=5,method='ols')
print(cor)
[ 1.          0.6        -0.32307692 -0.62857143 -1.8         1.84782609
```

When the lags are 4 and 5, autocorrelation is out of the range from -1 to 1. 
I know I am doing something wrong but cannot put a finger on it.
 Please tell me.

]

Comment: It seems that the issue could have to do with having nlags large relative to the size of the array. There's some discussion on this [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/122337-wrong-function-partial-autocorrelation-pacf-parcorr-greater-than-1-1)

Comment: @cnapun, thnk for the comment. Is it mean the arry size has to be larger?, and how much of size is it proper?